# How do I handle prerelease gems on my gem server?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am currently running a gem server for our company that stores our local in house gems.  We are currently using the default rubygems server that is invoked with `gem server`.  However whenever we fetch from this server (using bundler) we get:

`Could not fetch prerelease specs from rubygems repository http://rubygems.myserver.org`

The server works fine otherwise, but we would actually like to have our server support prerelease anyhow.  Is anyone running a gem server successfully with prerelease?  If so what server are you using and how?  I cannot seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is not to use gem server, but use a regular web server then execute `gem generate_index`.  This successfully built prerelease and regular indexes.

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18 section 4.2